# Show that [3,4] x [5,6] is closed?

Tags: general-topology

[3,4] is closed in R <-- R-[3,4] is open

[5,6] is closed in R <-- R-[5,6] is open

Show that [3,4] x [5,6] is closed in R x R by writing it as the complement of the intersection of two open sets in R x R.

(R - [3,4]) x (R - [5,6]) not equal R x R - [3,4] x [5,6]

Comment: I think you want intersection of complements, not complement of intersection.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What are your thoughts on the problem? People here expect to see the effort you made. Also, have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: Seems convoluted by if you let $A = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ and through a combinations of a unions and intersections we can show $B = \{(x,y)| x < 3$ or $x > 4$ or ($3\le x \le 4$ AND ($y < 5$ or $y > 6$))$\}$ is open, then we have $A\cap B = B = ([3,4]\times [5,6])^c$.  We can do other thing like the entire plane minus half a rectangle intersected the entire plane minus the other half a rectangle. (So the intersectinon is the full plane minus the rectangle) but those all seem contrived and silly.  I suspect user10354138 is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$\Bbb R^2 - ([3,4] \times [5,6]) = ((\Bbb R - [3,4]) \times \Bbb R) \cup (\Bbb R \times(\Bbb R - [5,6]))$$ so that $\Bbb R^2 - ([3,4] \times [5,6])$ is a union of basic open sets hence open, and so $[3,4] \times [5,6]$ is closed.

You can also directly write $$[3,4] \times [5,6] = \pi_1^{-1}[[3,4]] \cap \pi_2^{-1}[[5,6]]$$

which is the intersection of closed sets (as the projections are continuous) and hence closed.

Comment: It was supposed to be the _intersection_ of two open sets.

Comment: @amsmath union is more natural. You could try intersection yourself...

Comment: It doesn't matter what's more natural. The task is to write is as an intersection, and you didn't.

Comment: @amsmath the exercise might be wrong. I strongly suspect so.

Comment: Yes, I think so, too.

Comment: @amsmath The intersection of two basic open sets is basic open. And the complement of $[3,4]\times [5,6]$ is not basic open.

Comment: You can only do if you allow the open sets in the complement to be themselves *unions* of (sub)basic open sets as @fleablood has done. But then I like my union solution better as it follows straight  from de Morgan, essentially.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think the exercise was badly written and incorrect.  But we can do it.

Let $A = \{(x,y)| x < 3\}; B= \{(x,y)|y< 5\}; C= \{(x,y)|x>4\}; D=\{(x,y)|y>6\}$ then $U = A\cup B \cup C \cup D$ is open.

And $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ is also open.

So $U\cap (\mathbb R \times \mathbb R) = U$ and $U^c = \{(x,y)| 3\le x\le 4$ and $5 \le y \le 6\}= [3,4]\times [5,6]$ is closed.

....

which is *really* stupid and convoluted.

....

To be an iota less contrived we could add $E= \{(x,y)| y > x-2\}$ and $F=\{(x,y)|y < x-2\}$ and if $U= A\cup B \cup C \cup D \cup E$ and $W = A\cup B \cup C \cup D \cup F$ then $U \cap W= ([3,4]\times [5,6])^c$.